# Why every central simple algebra has a splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a central simple $F$-algebra over a field $F$.
A field $E$ such that $F \subset E$ is called a *splitting field* for $A$ if $A \otimes E$ is isomorphic to $M_n (E)$ (as $E$-algebras) for some $n$.

> Why is the algebraic closure of $F$ a splitting field for $A$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\bar F$ the algebraic closure of $F$ and let $A$ be a csa over $F$.

Then $A\otimes\bar F$ is a central simple algebra over $\bar F$. Wedderburn's theorem tells us that there is a finite dimensional $\bar F$-algebra and an $n\geq1$ such that $A\otimes\bar F\cong M_n(D)$. Since $\bar F$ is algebraically closed, there are no non-trivial finite dimensional division $\bar F$-algebras, so $D=\bar F$.

This means that $\bar F$ splits $A$.

Comment: Can you please explain why $A \otimes_F \bar{F}$ is a simple ring?

Comment: Well, this is a standard property of central simple algebras: when you extend scalars they remain central and simple. You should consult any textbook on the subject!

Comment: Ok thanks. I just know the general situation when $A$ is semisimple, and then scalar extensions can fail to be semisimple.

Comment: @Dune The Tensor product of a central simple algebra with a simple algebra is always simple.